# UIImageView not finishing animation in modal view controller: how to check if something is cancelling animation?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

The `rotateView` function below indefinitely rotates a UIView and works fine except when invoked on a UIImageView presented in a modal UIViewController.

The problem is `finished` is `false` instead of `true`, so the animation stops after one rotation instead of continuing indefinitely. The only place where animations on this UIImageView are cancelled is what you see below. If you remove the check against `finished` the UIImageView rotates as expected.

Is there something particular about a modal UIViewController that alters animation of UIViews?

How can you check if something else is cancelling animation on the UIImageView? (Maybe something else is unexpectedly cancelling the animation.)

```
    // Animate loading view?
    if !loadingImageView.hidden {
        rotateView(loadingImageView)
    } else {
        loadingImageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
    // Do stuff

// Rotate <targetView> indefinitely
func rotateView(targetView: UIView, duration: Double = 1.0) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveLinear, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        targetView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(targetView.transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
    }) { finished in
        if finished {
            rotateView(targetView, duration: duration)
        }
    }
}
```